# Saving NSMutableArray into the plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, serialization

I am trying to save data in to the plist. I have one `NSObject` class having six `NSString` variables and I am storing the object in an `NSMutableArray`. How can I store this `NSMutableArray` into the plist?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices (maybe more, but these are the two that come to mind):

1. [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. `NSArray`'s method, [`– writeToFile:atomically`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a):

You could also write a method in your class to save out and read in this data since it is all `NSString`s.

Comment: Awesome.. I was not aware of NSPropertyListSerialization class. Thanks to share.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Archive/Unarchiving. Take a look at [this](http://samsoff.es/posts/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding).

Comment: Actually, I always archive and never use plists. :)